# I want to request below things with ruby unirest but I can't do that

Tags: ruby, rubygems, unirest

This is request

```
 POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
 Host: api.quizlet.com
 Authorization: Basic N0pIMzhUMjd6TTpOM3JYd3l2TU5OWlNGQWNBd0ozZ3lH
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
 grant_type=authorization_code&code=GENERATED_CODE
```

This is response

```
{
    "access_token": "46a54395f3d1108feca56c7f6ca8dd3d",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "scope": "read",
    "user_id": "ryu_nishida"
}
```

This is my code

```
 Unirest.post "http://api.quizlet.com/oauth/token", 
 headers:{ Authorization: "Basic 
 N0pIMzhUMjd6TTpOM3JYd3l2TU5OWlNGQWNBd0ozZ3lH"}, 
 grant_type=authorization_code&code=GENERATED_CODE
```

There are no responses from my code but it doesn't exist any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the response object in a variable,

```
response = Unirest.post("http://api.quizlet.com/oauth/token",
             auth:{:user=>"username", :password=>"password"})
```

Then you have methods to get details

```
response.code # Status code
response.headers # Response headers
response.body # Parsed body
response.raw_body # Unparsed body
```

Read the [`docs`](http://unirest.io/ruby.html)

Comment: I read docs but I couldn't understand where I should write grant_type.

Comment: It happened a error 

     SyntaxError in WordsController#new
     /Users/nishidaryu/RubymineProjects/share-
     tan/app/controllers/words_controller.rb:190: syntax error, unexpected ')', 
     expecting =>